# check duplicacy in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, last two elements are identical, i just want to check duplicate exist or not.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [crop] => CI-000001
            [type] => PT-000001
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [crop] => CI-000001
            [type] => PT-000003
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [crop] => CI-000005
            [type] => PT-000014
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [crop] => CI-000005
            [type] => PT-000014
        )

)
```

Comment: You're probably not the first one asking this, besides you have shown no effort of trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function of PHP as

```
$ara  = Array ( Array ( 'crop' => 'CI-000001', 'type' => 'PT-000001' ), Array
    (
        'crop' => 'CI-000001',
        'type' => 'PT-000003'
    ), Array
    (
        'crop' => 'CI-000005',
        'type' => 'PT-000014'
    ), Array
    (
        'crop' => 'CI-000005',
        'type' => 'PT-000014'
    )
);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_unique($ara,SORT_REGULAR));
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [crop] => CI-000001
            [type] => PT-000001
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [crop] => CI-000001
            [type] => PT-000003
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [crop] => CI-000005
            [type] => PT-000014
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?php
$array = array(array('crop' => 'CI-000001','type' => 'PT-000001'), array('crop' => 'CI-000001','type' => 'PT-000003'),array('crop' => 'CI-000005','type' => 'PT-000014'),array('crop' => 'CI-000005','type' => 'PT-000014'));
$array = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
echo "After Remove Duplicate:".'<pre>';
print_r( $array );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:-**

```
After Remove Duplicate:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [crop] => CI-000001
            [type] => PT-000001
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [crop] => CI-000001
            [type] => PT-000003
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [crop] => CI-000005
            [type] => PT-000014
        )

)
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2oyvno)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$hashes=array();
foreach ($myarray as $key=>$item) {
  $hash=sha1(var_export($item, true));
  if (isset($hashes($hash)) echo "$key is a duplicate of ".$hashes[$hash];
  else $hashes[$hash]=$key;
}
```